# How can i get the correct utc offset in javascript when the dst in mexico was permanently removed?

Tags: javascript, timezone, dst, rrule

I am using the RRule library in JavaScript and I've noticed that when I retrieve a date range, it returns the date and time in UTC but it is incorrect. The code looks like this:

```
return new RRule(removeUndefinedFromObject({
   dtstart: utcToZonedTime(params.start, params.timezone),
   freq: RRule.DAILY,
   byweekday: params.weekdays.map((day) => weekdaysMap[day]),
   until: utcToZonedTime(params.end, params.timezone),
   tzid: params.timezone,
}));
```

When the start is 2023-04-01 12:00:00, the end is 2023-04-04 18:00:00 and the timezone America/Mexico_City.

I am expecting the following date ranges:

| start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-01 12:00:00 | 2023-04-01 18:00:00 |
| 2023-04-02 12:00:00 | 2023-04-02 18:00:00 |
| 2023-04-03 12:00:00 | 2023-04-03 18:00:00 |
| 2023-04-04 12:00:00 | 2023-04-04 18:00:00 |

But i am getting:

| start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-01 12:00:00 | 2023-04-01 18:00:00 |
| 2023-04-02 11:00:00 | 2023-04-02 17:00:00 |
| 2023-04-03 11:00:00 | 2023-04-03 17:00:00 |
| 2023-04-04 11:00:00 | 2023-04-04 17:00:00 |

The government of Mexico removed Daylight Saving Time in October 2022, so the time should remain constant. However, I am encountering different times in April due to the previous implementation of Daylight Saving Time. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue in JavaScript? I've encountered similar problems with other libraries, such as date-fns."

Update: The problem was the version of nodejs, i was using nodejs 14.x but after updating to 18.x it is working as expected.

Comment: I don't believe this is something you fix in Javascript, but should be something the browser handles.

Answer (score 2):

Both RRule and date-fns-tz take their data from `Intl` in JavaScript, so you'll get whatever time zone data is provided by the runtime environment.

The change you mentioned for Mexico was released in [IANA 2022f](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V18.md#2023-01-05-version-18130-hydrogen-lts-danielleadams), October 29, 2022.  Assuming you're running server-side in Node.js, simply update Node to the current release.  You'll find tzdata 2022f mentioned in the changelog for Node.js  [18.13.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V18.md#2023-01-05-version-18130-hydrogen-lts-danielleadams) (LTS) and also [19.2.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V19.md#2022-11-29-version-1920-current-ruyadorno) (current).

Comment: Note, the full data path is IANA -> ICU -> Node -> Intl.  However, ICU's data can be updated out-of-band, which Node does regularly.

Comment: As far as older Node versions, 2022f also made it into Node 16.19.0 and 14.21.2.